# Is there JSON library in Java to easily replace a value in a JSON tree where I only know the value but not field/key that maps to it?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson

I have a JsonNode (Jackson) object and I'd like to replace a specific value in it. Is there a Json library that can help find a field that maps to a specific value or do I need to recursively traverse through it.

For example, I'd like to replace the placeholder in the below json with some object. I am wondering if there is an there is an API from Jackson or some other library that I can leverage to do it one line. Note that I don't know the field I am searching for but I do know the value is "{replaceValueHereWithAnyObject}".

```
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "new": {
                "abc": "{replaceValueHereWithAnyObject}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ObjectNode.replace(...) only seems to take in field as an input and replace the value for that field. In my case, I don't know which field is mapped to the known value that I'd like to replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a library (and incidentally, asking for a library recommendation is likely to get a question closed as "off topic"), but it's not that hard to do it yourself. Here's a snippet of code for recursive traversal and in-place editing. It only looks at text nodes, and the replacement is always a text node, but you can adapt it to your needs.

```
// Walk the JSON tree and modify textual fields in-place.
public static void transformTextFields(JsonNode node, Function<String, String> transformer) {
  if (node.isObject()) {
    // take a snapshot of the field names to avoid concurrent modification
    final List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>(node.size());
    node.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(fieldNames::add);

    for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
      final JsonNode child = node.get(fieldName);
      if (child.isContainerNode()) {
        transformTextFields(child, transformer);
      } else if (child.isTextual()) {
        final String oldValue = child.textValue();
        ((ObjectNode) node).set(fieldName, new TextNode(transformer.apply(oldValue)));
      }
    }
  } else if (node.isArray()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < node.size(); i++) {
      final JsonNode child = node.get(i);
      if (child.isContainerNode()) {
        transformTextFields(child, transformer);
      } else if (child.isTextual()) {
        final String oldValue = child.textValue();
        ((ArrayNode) node).set(i, new TextNode(transformer.apply(oldValue)));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Invoke it like this:

```
transformTextFields(myJsonNode, fieldValue -> replaceMyPlaceholder(fieldValue));
```